# What is the saturation of /feed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a Minecraft 1.7.10 server running, and I have the Essentials plugin installed. It comes with `/feed` which fills the user's health, but I had a question about the command itself. Each food item in Minecraft when eaten will make its given hunger last a certain amount of time, and usually that is displayed either in-game, or on a wiki. What I have not been able to determine is what the saturation of /feed is! Being a command, it does not have a GUI display, so it cannot be checked in-game, and I have not been able to find it on the web. The only semi-helpful link was [this server's forum page,](http://forums.cobalt-mc.com/index.php?threads/donor-feed-command-saturation-level.3999/) but even that didn't give a definite answer. After the saturation is determined, I would like to change /feed to have much higher saturation if at all possible.

Comment: You're profile picture is awesome! While this question fits here, I'd also recommend asking on the forum of Essentials plugin as the people there might know the answer better. Be sure to self answer here if you learn the answer too!

Comment: @ardaozkal Thanks! I'll make sure to do that, and see if anyone there can help me solve this. If I do get an answer I'll definitely post it!

Answer (score 2):

According to the Essentials GitHub repository, the /feed command sets a player's saturation to 10. Source: [Here](https://github.com/essentials/Essentials/blob/2.x/Essentials/src/com/earth2me/essentials/commands/Commandfeed.java) (See line 73)

Comment: Although this is telling me the saturation, I still have no clue how to change it.

Comment: It cannot be changed without rewriting the class, as the value is hardcoded.

Comment: Still not helpful. How do I rewrite the class?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be for me to make you another /feed cmd with customisable saturation

Comment: Okay, that would be great but I'll also need instructions on how to install that

Comment: Add me on skype: mariolord640